# Docker: Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: ./conf/flow.xml.gz: Resource busy

Tags: docker, docker-compose, apache-nifi

I have this definition of Nifi container in `docker-compose.yml` file. I changed the default Nifi port from 8080 to 8181. It works correctly. However, I cannot copy `flow.xml.gz` to Nifi container.

```
  nifi:
    image: xemuliam/nifi
    network_mode: "host"
    ports:
      - "8181:8181"
    expose:
      - "8181"
    environment:
      - NIFI_WEB_HTTP_PORT=8181
      - NIFI_WEB_HTTP_HOST=0.0.0.0
    volumes:
      - ./src/data_flow_engine/flow.xml.gz:/opt/nifi/conf/flow.xml.gz
      - ./src/data_flow_engine/bootstrap.conf:/opt/nifi/conf/bootstrap.conf
```

When I comment out `- ./src/data_flow_engine/flow.xml.gz:/opt/nifi/conf/flow.xml.gz`, then it runs well.

This is the error message:

```
2018-11-02 12:49:47,818 INFO [main] org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server Started @41290ms
nifi_1           | 2018-11-02 12:49:47,818 WARN [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer Failed to start web server... shutting down.
nifi_1           | org.apache.nifi.web.NiFiCoreException: Unable to start Flow Controller.
nifi_1           |  at org.apache.nifi.web.contextlistener.ApplicationStartupContextListener.contextInitialized(ApplicationStartupContextListener.java:88)
nifi_1           |  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:876)
nifi_1           |  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:532)
nifi_1           |  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:839)
nifi_1           |  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:344)
nifi_1           |  at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1480)
nifi_1           |  at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1442)
nifi_1           |  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:799)
nifi_1           |  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:261)
nifi_1           |  at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:540)
nifi_1           |  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
nifi_1           |  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
nifi_1           |  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
nifi_1           |  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
nifi_1           |  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
nifi_1           |  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
nifi_1           |  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
nifi_1           |  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
nifi_1           |  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.doStart(GzipHandler.java:290)
nifi_1           |  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
nifi_1           |  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
nifi_1           |  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
nifi_1           |  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
nifi_1           |  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
nifi_1           |  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
nifi_1           |  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:452)
nifi_1           |  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
nifi_1           |  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
nifi_1           |  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:419)
nifi_1           |  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
nifi_1           |  at org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer.start(JettyServer.java:777)
nifi_1           |  at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:157)
nifi_1           |  at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:71)
nifi_1           |  at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.main(NiFi.java:292)
nifi_1           | Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: ./conf/flow.xml.gz: Resource busy
nifi_1           |  at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:91)
nifi_1           |  at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
nifi_1           |  at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
nifi_1           |  at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.implDelete(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:244)
nifi_1           |  at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.deleteIfExists(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:108)
nifi_1           |  at java.nio.file.Files.deleteIfExists(Files.java:1165)
nifi_1           |  at org.apache.nifi.persistence.StandardXMLFlowConfigurationDAO.save(StandardXMLFlowConfigurationDAO.java:165)
nifi_1           |  at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService.load(StandardFlowService.java:536)
nifi_1           |  at org.apache.nifi.web.contextlistener.ApplicationStartupContextListener.contextInitialized(ApplicationStartupContextListener.java:72)
nifi_1           |  ... 33 common frames omitted
nifi_1           | 2018-11-02 12:49:47,819 INFO [Thread-1] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Initiating shutdown of Jetty web server...
nifi_1           | 2018-11-02 12:49:47,820 INFO [Thread-1] o.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector Stopped ServerConnector@41d0b71d{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8181}
nifi_1           | 2018-11-02 12:49:47,823 INFO [Thread-1] org.eclipse.jetty.server.session Stopped scavenging
```

Answer (score 3):

Mapping the `flow.xml.gz` file does not seem to work (I tested with apache/nifi-1.8.0 and got the same result as you).

Mapping the entire `/conf` directory into the container worked for me. Here is the docker-compose file I am using:

```
version: "3.5"

services:
  nifi:
    image: apache/nifi:1.8.0
    ports:
      - "8181:8080"
    environment:
      - NIFI_WEB_HTTP_HOST=0.0.0.0
    volumes:
      - ./conf:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/
```

In this case, my local ./conf directory is an entire NiFi configuration directory, containing:

```
conf
├── authorizers.xml
├── bootstrap-notification-services.xml
├── bootstrap.conf
├── flow.xml.gz
├── logback.xml
├── login-identity-providers.xml
├── nifi.properties
├── state-management.xml
└── zookeeper.properties
```

If you do not already have a conf directory to use as a starting point, you can get it by copying it out of the convenience binaries provided by the Apache project corresponding to the version of the Docker image you are using. In my example, I used the conf directory from the nifi-1.8.0.zip available from [nifi.apache.org](https://nifi.apache.org/download.html). Note that some files in that directory are created in that directory by NiFi at runtime.